# PowerShell says "The parameter is incorrect" when attempting to create a scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to make a script that creates a task in task scheduler that runs every 2 months at 7:00 PM that will run Dell Command Update, install updates, and reboot if necessary.

When running this script I just get an error about the parameter being incorrect (`The parameter is incorrect.`), with the category being: `InvalidArgument`.

Below is the code I am running.

```
$TaskName = "DellCommandUpdateTask"

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Program Files\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe" -Argument "/scan -silent /applyUpdates -silent -reboot=enable"

$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -WeeksInterval 8 -At "19:00"

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -Trigger $Trigger -Action $action
```

I tried some different combinations of `'` and `"` around the execute action.

I think the issue may be in the `$action` part of this code, but I am not sure.

Comment: Post the (complete) error message please. (formatted as code as well please)

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify the symptoms. However, even before that the problem was easily reproducible, which is arguably more important than spelling out the full details of the error message and, crucially, reproducibility is sufficient for being able to offer a solution. Therefore, I think the closure of this question was premature, and likely discouraging to the poster. /cc @Olaf.

Comment: @mklement0 I did not vote to close the question.  ‍♂️

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Olaf. I hope you agree with the sentiment I've expressed.

Comment: @mklement0, I did not vote to close, but I did vote to reopen because there is an (you provided) answer. However, I am reluctant to encourage this methodology. The act of gathering the error messages is an activity that an OP should do. For me, I have sometimes found that gathering all of the details in order to post a question leads me to some revelation meaning that I do not need to post a question. :-)

Comment: @lit, no argument there. Unquestionably, providing all relevant context _to the extent necessary_ (and knowing what that extent is is obviously a challenge) is preferable: It makes the life of potential answerers easier and may make the difference as to whether they'll even bother to answer. It is also commendable to _educate newcomers_ with respect to what makes a good question. My concern is about question getting reflexively closed due to not meeting some _formal_ criteria, especially shortly after posting - but I also get that users want to cast their close vote in the moment and move on.

Comment: On a meta note, @Olaf: My /cc-ing you doesn't necessarily imply criticism of your actions; it is an attempt to notify you of information you may find interesting/relevant.  (Even addressing you directly, _without_ /cc, may fall into that category, situationally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't your `New-ScheduledTaskAction` call, it is your `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` call:

You neglected to specify a *day of the week* (possibly multiple) on which to run your task:

For instance, to run on Sundays, use `-DaysOfWeek Sunday`:

```bash
$Trigger = 
  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -WeeksInterval 8 -At 19:00 -DaysOfWeek Sunday
```

Your own attempt amounted to an *incomplete* scheduled-task trigger specification, and it is unfortunate that [`New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger) doesn't itself prevent that, resulting in an - obscure - error message only *later*, at the time of calling [`Register-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask) (`The parameter is incorrect.`)

---

As an aside:

- Because you didn't also pass a `-Principal` argument to your `Register-ScheduledTask` call, the task will run in the context of the  *calling user*, and only when that user is *logged on*.
- Use [`New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskprincipal) to obtain a different task principal (user identity), which allows you to run the task independently of any given user and independently of whether someone is logged on or not.